# AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for UserSessionsController):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, action, usersession

I have some problems with my ruby app.
I use:
Ruby  = 2.0
Rails = 3.2

**When i try to logout, i has an error like this bellow.**

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be found for UserSessionsController:
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:116:in `process'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`process'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
>     journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in`block in call'
>     journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in`call'
>     bullet (4.1.4) lib/bullet/rack.rb:8:in `call'
>     hirefire-resource (0.1.2) lib/hirefire/middleware.rb:27:in`call'
>     newrelic_rpm (3.6.2.96) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:12:in `call'
>     newrelic_rpm (3.6.2.96) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:18:in`call'
>     newrelic_rpm (3.6.2.96) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
>     newrelic_rpm (3.6.2.96) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in`call'
>     request_store (1.0.5) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in`context'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in`call'
>     activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
>     activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`*run*_4032778647788681780_*call*_3401891405258349156__callbacks'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`call'
>     better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
>     better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in`better_errors_call'
>     better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in`call_app'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in`tagged'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in`call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
>     rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
>     activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in`call'
>     actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in`call'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'
>     railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
>     rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in`service'
>     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

**This is my routes.rb:**

```
root to: 'user_session#new'
match '/user_sessions/new' => redirect('/user_session/new')
enter code here
controller :user_sessions do
get    'user_session/new'     => :new,  as: 'new_user_session'
get    'user_session/edit'    => :edit, as: 'edit_user_session'
get    'user_session'         => :show, as: 'user_session'
put    'user_session'         => :update
delete 'user_session'         => :destroy
post   'user_session'         => :create
end
```

**And also put this to user_session_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
current_user_session.destroy
redirect_to new_user_session_url
end
```

Comment: Make sure your javascripts are working without any errors.

Comment: Have you used `:method => :delete` in your link to logout?

Comment: @MarekLipka : what do mean by that? i dont get it, i'm new at ruby

Comment: @Santosh : i already did, in my view right method: :delete

Comment: @hypee : what do you mean?